# saving foreignkey instances in the createview in views.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-class-based-views

I've a models called job, application, attachments. when a job is already created an a user wants to apply for the job I get an integrity error that says `null value in column "job_id" violates not-null constraint`

If I add job in the fields part of  `class Meta` of `ApplicationForm` everything runs successful but when the user  select the job he whats to apply he is forced to select again  the job to fill in the job field,
So I want is to automatically add the job field to be added in createview in views.py

here is my code

models.py

```
class Application(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='applied_jobs',
         null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='applications', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    career_briefing = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)


class  Attachments(models.Model):
    application = models.ForeignKey(Application, related_name='attachments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cv = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
```

form.py

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cvs = forms.CharField(max_length=6000, widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('career_briefing',)
```

views.py

```
class ApplicationCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Application
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    message = _("succesfuly applied")
    template_name = 'jobs/application_form.html'
    message = _("successful")
    def form_valid(self, form):

        cvs = form.cleaned_data['cvs']               
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.job = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        apply = form.save(commit=False)
        apply.job = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        apply.user = self.request.user
        apply.save()

        doc = Attachments(cv=cvs)
        doc.application = apply

        doc.save() 

        return super(ApplicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, self.message)
        return reverse("jobs:list")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
          ....
    url(r'^details/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', JobDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^details/apply/$', ApplicationCreateView.as_view(), name='apply'),
        .....
]
```

What I expect is that  a user submits the application form successful but i get an `integrity error " null value in column "job_id" violates not-null constraint ",`
For me I think the `job instance` is not saved ,if this is the real problem may someone please show me how to solve it,
If that's not the problem may someone help me out with this
thanks in advance

Comment: Does the URL actually contain a pk?

Comment: it does not contain a pk @DanielRoseman

Comment: and i have updated the question just adding the urls

Comment: So then how do you expect this to work? You've written code that takes the job value from the pk parameter in the URL, so surely you must actually provide that?

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it ,i know this is  dumb question but it is quite hard for a beginner like me  with few weeks in django , Thanks in advance